# Proving that function has a locally strict minimum at $0$

Tags: calculus, optimization

Take the function $f(\alpha p)=3\alpha^4p_1^4-4\alpha^3p_1^2p_2+\alpha^2p_2^2$.
Then with respect to $\alpha$:

$$f'(\alpha p)=12\alpha^3p_1^4-12\alpha^2p_1^2p_2+2\alpha p_2^2$$
$$f''(\alpha p) = 36\alpha^2p_1^4-24\alpha p_1^2p_2+2p_2^2$$

We need to show that $f$ has a locally strict minimum at $0$ along every line passing through the origin.
Clearly $f'(0)=0$ and $f''(0)=2p_2^2$. Now the latter is strictly positive iff $p_2 \neq 0$. Now the question remains how to prove that the minimum at $0$ also exists iff $p_2=0$.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: When $p_2=0$ it is obvious. Just look at what happens when $\lvert \alpha \rvert$ is very small

Comment: I'm not sure? When $|\alpha|$ is very small $f''$ tends to $0$?

Comment: No, too complicated. If $p_2=0$, then $f$ has a very nice structure. Just argue with $f$.